# UILongPressGestureRecognizer Turns Off UIButton Highlighting

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have a UILongPressGestureRecognizer added to a UIButton. When I press the UIButton it gets highlighted as expected. However, when the UILongPressGestureRecognizer selector gets called the highlighting gets turned off.

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture = 
     [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(longPressHandler:)];
    longpressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 5;
    [longpressGesture setDelegate:self];
    [self.myUIButton addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];
    [longpressGesture release];

    - (void)longPressHandler:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"longPressHandler");
}
```

In the above example, the selector gets called after 5 seconds of holding down the button. The button is highlighted prior to the selector being called, but then gets unhighlighted when the selector is called, even though I am still pressing the button.

Can anyone explain why this happens, and how it can be prevented? I would like the button to remain highlighted the entire time while pressed down. Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After further research, I discovered that this is due to the default behavior of Gesture Recognizers, which cancel touches in the hierarchy once they recognize a gesture. So, once the Gesture Recognizer recognizes a gesture, it cancels the touch to the UI Button, which then gets unhighlighted, since it no longer has a touch event.

This behavior can be changed using the **cancelsTouchesInView** property

```
longpressGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Setting this to NO will pass the touch through to the responder chain.

Comment: But it will call the selector for touchUpInside. How to prevent that??

Comment: @user1010819 did you find some solution for this problem? I am facing same problem..

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat speculative..: I suspect the firing of the GestureRecognizer is taking the buttons place in the responder chain, which makes it loose focus. I can't think of any way to prevent this, but there may be some workarounds:

- in the long press handler method manipulate the button to continue to show the pressed state. This is propably a very dirty way to do this.
- don't use the gesture recognizer. Instead, immediately when the button has been pressed create a timer which after 5 seconds is calling some selector. If the button is being released before the time has elapsed, simply invalidate the timer. This should be a more "clean" solution, however, if you're determined to use the gesture recognizer, this won't help..